# Are the Performances of these two programs the same?

Tags: c++, performance, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Say for example you have a linked list 1->2->3->4->5->6->NULL and you want to calculate the total of the even indices of that linked list (assuming that the 1st index starts with 1 and the size of the linked list is even)

## First Approach

```
int total = 0;
int count = 0;
Node *ptr = head;
while(ptr != NULL)
{
    if(count % 2 == 0)
     {
       total += ptr->data;
     }
     count++;
     ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

## Second Approach

```
int total = 0;
Node *ptr = head;
while(ptr != NULL)
{  
    total += ptr->data;
     ptr = ptr->next->next;
}
```

So after I did these two approaches do they have the same performance?

Comment: The second approach could easily have undefined behavior if there is an odd number of nodes.

Comment: Measure it, but be aware that traversing the entirety of a linked list is probably going to outweigh the difference by a lot if that's what's going in outside of this example.

Comment: If you measure create 10 thousand nodes and then time both algorithms using std::chrono. Make sure you are using an optimized / release build. Related to timing: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock/now](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock/now)

Comment: The second will likely be slightly (very slightly) faster, and infinitely less safe.

Comment: You could unroll the operation as `while (ptr) { total += ptr->data; ptr = ptr->next; if (ptr) ptr = ptr->next; }` and this saves essentially an addition, a modulo and a register but maintains the same amount of branching.  Maybe a clever optimizing compiler would do this anyway.  I think that's premature optimization, as already cited by others that linked list traversal is slow in general due to increased chance of cache misses.  In the end, either use your first example or mine - the choice should primarily be to use the one that most clearly describes the intent to anyone reading the code.

Comment: In C++ use `nullptr` in preference to C's `NULL`. Unless this is purely academic code, use `std::list` instead of your own kitbashed linked list.

Comment: To avoid branching you could do `total += (count % 2 == 0) * ptr->data;` but could be slower due to the additional multiplication and addition and everything the others said still stands. It's premature optimization, you should profile it, and it's a linked list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read your question again and will answer that *probably* the second method is slightly faster.

Now, the comments section immediately highlighted that it's also more dangerous.  You have actually specified that the assumption is the number of nodes in the list is even.  If that is a guaranteed and enforceable precondition, then it's technically okay to do this.

Even a smart optimizing compiler has no way of knowing about this precondition of even list-length, so the very best it could likely achieve is to recognize that `count` is only used for controlling whether `total` is updated and so the loop could be unrolled as follows:

```
// Possible automatic compiler optimization of First Approach
while (ptr)
{
    total += ptr->data;
    ptr = ptr->next;

    // Skip over every second node
    if (ptr) ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

In basic terms, what we now have is one more pointer test (branch) per loop iteration than your Second Approach has.  This results in more instructions (specifically a branching instruction) and so the code will technically be (slightly) slower.

Of course, the actual impact of this is likely to be very small.  Your main bottleneck is pointer indirection and fetches from memory, rather than the pointer test itself.  If the memory used by each node is not mostly contiguous, you'll run into caching problems on large lists (which in practice affects performance by about a factor of 100).

What I mean to indicate by all the above, is that the benefits of your special optimization based on the precondition of even list-length suffers from diminishing returns.

Given that it is inherently unsafe unless very well-documented in the code and/or protected by a list "evenness" test (if you store the node count somewhere), I would recommend coding defensively by using your First Approach or use my equivalent and (arguably) tidier version of that.

Comment: I want to add a caveat about your First Approach.  The "unrolled" version is in fact safer than either of your two approaches because it does not rely on a count variable that can overflow if you have a very large list leading to undefined behavior (or at least implementation-specific behavior) when a signed value overflows.  And of course it does not rely on the list being of even length.